# AngularJS template in directive variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to know if there is a way to set a template path for a variable in directive ?
I have kind of this code:

```
  tooltip = "<img src={{object.avatar}}>" + {{object.fullname}}
```

And I would like to have a file in templates/ like tooltip.html.haml and set my template inside. So I could have in my directive:

```
tooltip = "../templates/tooltip.html.haml"
```

Or another path if necessary.

Is it possible?

The end of my directive:

```
linker = (scope, element, attrs) ->
  element.html(tooltip).show()
  $compile(element.contents()) scope

restrict: "E"
replace: true
scope:
  object: "="
link: linker
```

Thanks by advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use template or templateUrl parameters of directive object

```
linker = (scope, element, attrs) ->
element.html(tooltip).show()
$compile(element.contents()) scope

restrict: "E"
templateUrl: "tooltip.html"  // or
template: "<img src='{{object.avatar}}'>"
replace: true
scope:
object: "="
```

link: linker

Comment: my object.avatar is displayed good, I have the good path get from by bdd. But I would like to put all this code in a template to have like an html file with blocks readable.

Comment: @guillaumek oh, i got you wrong, use `template` or `templateUrl` parameter of directive (look up here , long version http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)